# Condição para continuar loop enquanto valor for inválido

Tags: algoritmo, condição, visualg, portugol

Queria saber sobre este código:

```
Algoritmo "Brincadeira2Ou1 "

  Var   A, C, P: inteiro

Inicio

      A <- 0
      C <- 0
      P <- 0
      escreval ("(=====================2===OU===1=====================)")
      escreval ("Insira o número do (A)ndré: ")
      leia (A)
           enquanto (A <= 1) ou (A >= 2) faca
                    escreval ("Número inválido! Número deve ser 1 ou 2")
                    escreval ("Por favor, digite novamente um número para André:")
                    leia (A)
           fimenquanto
```

Ali na estrutura do `enquanto (A <= 1) ou (A >= 2)`, quando eu faço o `A` receber 1 ou 2, ele fica retornando a linha do `escreval` de que o `Número é inválido`, sendo que precisa ser 1 ou 2 (mesmo eu digitando 1 ou 2 o sistema volta como número inválido).

No momento que eu retiro o `=`, o código roda validando o 1 ou 2 que inseri. Não seria o certo ser **A menor ou igual a 1 ou A maior ou igual a 2** do que o **A menor que 1 ou A maior que 2**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A <= 1
```

quer dizer que se for o valor 1 (é igual) ou (os menores) 0, ou -1, ou -2, etc. tá valendo.

```
A >= 2
```

quer dizer que se for o valor 2 (é igual) ou (os maiores) 3, ou 4, ou 5, etc. tá valendo.

Então quais não estão valendo? Nenhum. O que tem entre o 1 e o 2? Nada.

Como as duas condições são conectadas com um `OU` qualquer uma sendo verdadeira é verdadeiro.

Quando você substitui o menor ou igual por um menor e o maior ou igual por um maior tudo muda:

```
A < 1
```

quer dizer que se for os valores **menores** que 1, ou seja, 0, ou -1, ou -2, etc. tá valendo.

```
A > 2
```

quer dizer que se for o valores **maiores** que 2, ou seja, 3, ou 4, ou 5, etc. tá valendo.

Agora o 1 e o 2 não entraram na lista, então eles são dados diferentes. Se o valor dor 1 dá falso em uma das condições. Se o valor for 2 dá falso na outra. Qualquer uma delas dando verdadeiro a expressão toda é verdadeira porque precisa ser uma ou outra, não precisa ser a duas. Só dará falso se ambas forem falsas. Então precisa que o número nem seja 1 e nem seja 2 ao mesmo tempo para dar falso.

Eu prefiro escrever o código assim:

```
Algoritmo "Brincadeira2Ou1"
    Var A: inteiro
Inicio
    A <- 0
    escreval("(=====================2===OU===1=====================)")
    enquanto verdadeiro faca
        escreval("Insira o número do (A)ndré: ")
        leia(A)
        if A == 1 ou A == 2
            sair //não sei se é assim no seu pseudo código seria um break aqui
        escreval("Número inválido! Número deve ser 1 ou 2")
    fimenquanto
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/Loop.ptg).

Eu acho mais lógico, intuitivo e mais [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101), mas por alguma razão as pessoas não costumam fazer.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, me ajudou demais! Eu percebi que não estava fazendo muito sentido do jeito que eu estava fazendo, preciso melhorar ainda e muito, um dia chego lá. Nesse caso vi também que os conectivos fazem uma diferença tremenda. Acabei por optar o A <> 1 com conectivo E. esse Pseudo com Visualg 3 estou fazendo o "jogo" do 2 ou 1, entre 3 pessoas, qual der números iguais da empate, um diferente ganha e assim por diante. Muito obrigado novamente.

Answer (score 2):

Todo número inteiro é menor ou igual a 1 **ou** maior ou igual a 2.

O zero? É menor que 1 (e portanto `<= 1`).
O `1`? É igual a 1 (e portanto `<= 1`).
O `2`? É igual a 2 (e portanto `>= 2`).
O `3`? É maior que 2 (e portanto `>= 2`).

Ou seja, ao fazer `enquanto (A <= 1) ou (A >= 2)`, basicamente o loop vai continuar rodando indefinidamente, já que qualquer número digitado satisfaz a condição.

Ao tirar o sinal de igual (`enquanto (A < 1) ou (A > 2)`), você considera que a condição para que o loop continue é que o número seja menor que 1 **ou** maior que 2. Mas se o número for 1 ou 2, aí não satisfaz mais a condição do loop e ele se encerra.

---

Mas neste caso, como você só quer continuar o loop se o número não for 1 nem 2, uma forma - na minha opinião - mais clara seria:

```
enquanto (A != 1) e (A != 2)
```

Ou seja, enquanto o valor for diferente de 1 **e** diferente de 2, continua executando o loop.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta! Eu percebi que não estava fazendo muito sentido, preciso melhorar ainda e muito, um dia chego lá. Nesse caso vi também que os conectivos fazem uma diferença gigantesca. Acabei por optar o A <> 1 com conectivo E. Esse Pseudo com Visualg que estou fazendo é o "jogo" do 2 ou 1, entre 3 pessoas, qual der números iguais da empate, um diferente ganha e assim por diante. Muito obrigado novamente.